# I/O error from python3-wheel.list preventing me from downloading packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-wheel

So I've had this problem that's preventing me from downloading some python packages like psycopg2 and libbz2-dev that keeps coming up. The part of the terminal response is posted below.

Selecting previously unselected package bzip2-doc. dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  loading files list file for package 'python3-wheel': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-wheel.list (Input/output error) E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Python3.9

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What command(s) did you execute?

Comment: I used pipenv install X  (within a shell) or sudo apt-get install X outside of my pipenv shell on either installation.